# Hello world - what is a simple program to use 16GB of memory?

Tags: memory-management

How can I allocate a large amount of memory with 16GB ram? Please provide a simple C/C++ program as an example.

E.g.

```
main()
{
    // (10 gigabytes) / (4 bytes) = 2 684 354 560
    int *hugearray = malloc( 2684354560 * sizeof(int) );
}
```

...obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: Additionally to Philip's question, it's also of interest which OS you're on and whether you're in 32bit or 64bit mode because in 32bit mode you cannot address more that 2^32=4GB.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode values like that - you could write `10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` instead.

Answer (score 7):

`malloc()` does allocate the memory, but most OS will only give you a virtual address space until you actually try to read or write within that memory, at which time they'll start allocating backing physical or swap memory.  You simply need to loop writing some garbage values into the memory.

Comment: A simple call to memset() should do that for him.

Comment: @Tim Post: could well do, especially if using a non-0 value (I've a vague recollection re some OS being smart enough to undo the RAM/swap allocation when swapping out an all-0 page, but maybe I just read some discussion about it and not about an actual system that did it).

Answer (score 0):

Sample program works fine if you change the declaration from int to long.
I'm running Mint Linux on a 64-bit Intel-esque CPU with 16GB of memory.